# Error: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string'

Tags: c++, string, binary, cout, stdstring

My Question is similar to others but I wasn't able to find and answer that quite fit, maybe I'm just missing it, but anyways.

Given that this is at the top of my .cpp:

```
#include <cstring>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std
```

why would this line have an error:

```
cout << endl << output << endl;
```

the error being:

> binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: You didn't include the right header. I'm surprised I was able to deduce that from your question, though. Your title is of no use to anyone, and there's incomplete and unformatted code.

Comment: Hint: `<cstring>` and `<string>` are two very different things.

Comment: Where did you learn this syntax of `\#include`?

Comment: @texasbruce: That was his attempt to make the `#include` not appear in big bold letters.  Yu Hao formatted the code, but left the slashes in.

Comment: By the way, @user2971135, for future reference, just type your code exactly as you would in your text editor, but indented by 4 extra spaces.  If you select your code and click the button that looks like this: `{}`, it will do that indentation for you.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You are right, when I formatted the question, I followed the source only, `\\` isn't there in the original view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<cstring>` is the header for C strings, i.e, its content is the same as the C header `string.h`. What you need to handle `std::string` is `<string>`

Another problem is that you missed the semicolon:

```
using namespace std;
//                 ^
```

Note that this style works, but is not recommend, it's better not to use this line and use:

```
std::cout << std::endl << output << std::endl;
```

Comment: Or even better, `std::cout << '\n' << output << '\n';`.  With rare exceptions, needing `endl` means your buffering is set incorrectly.